# Container to show vertical scroll but allowing float overflows

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

How can I setup a container so when the window size is too small shows a scroll in order to see all the elements that doesn't fit in one go, but at the same time, if a child shows a floating elements it is allowed to exit the bounds of the container.

I am currently using a Material UI **Card**, which has some elements:
[image]

As you can see in the image, it works while using `overflow: auto` for the **CardContent**.

Unfortunately, the floating element for the *Combo1* component is not allowed to be shown outside:
[image]

And if I remove the overflow and/or set it to `overflow: visible`, the floating element shows fine but the contents doesn't scroll anymore:

[image]

Is there any way to allow only the floating elements to be shown outside a parent with hidden overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Your core issue is that A) if you have content inside an element, B) that content exceeds the element's width, and C) that element has an `overflow` style that hides content **that content will be hidden**.  This is just how CSS works.

Similarly, if you don't hide your overflow, there's no way to have the browser add scroll bars to that content.  So if you want scrolled content you have to have an appropriate `overflow` style (`auto` `scroll-y`, `scroll`) to get the scrolling you want.

The solution, which will feel unnatural in a React app (where you're used to keeping all your UI within your component's HTML element) is to keep any UI bits that need to be shown outside the overflow, *outside of the element with the overflow style*.

They can still be in the same component, they just have to be outside the main element.  Then, you can use some onComponentDidMount (`useEffect`) code to position that UI to appear next to the scrolling UI.  In other words, you can't change `overflow` or your DOM structure, but you can use CSS to make your UI *look* the way you desire with a different structure.

Something like:

```
const YourComponent => {
  useEffect(positionUiBitsNextToMainUIUsingRefsOrSomething);
  return <>
      <UIBits/>
      <div style={{overflow: 'auto'}}>
        <MainUI/>
      </div>
  </>;
}
```

As for doing the positioning part, you'll need to use refs (`useRef`) to access the DOM elements of your UI, so that you can position them.  Prior to React I would use jQuery UI's `position` function to do this sort of thing, but haven't needed to do this in React (or anywhere else) in a long time, so I don't have a better recommendation.

Whether you use a library or not though, essentially you'll want to use `position: absolute` styling (and some calculations on your main UI's position) to move the UI bits to where you want them.

Comment: The thing is the *Combo1* component is contained into itself as is a component I have in a "Components Library", so I don't see how I can put the floating element subchild outside the container that uses the component

Comment: The answer is CSS.  You have no choice but to adopt the core structure described in my answer (ie. `UIBits` has to be outside `MainUI` if you don't want `MainUI`'s `overflow` to hide it).  But if you add `position: absolute; top: 40px; right: 10px` (or *something like that*; again you'll have to calculate the exact numbers) you can make `UIBits` **look** like it's next to your inner elements.

Comment: See https://jqueryui.com/position/ for an example of this being done in JS ... but again I suspect there's a better/more modern NPM package you can use (which doesn't require all of jQuery and jQuery UI as a dependency) ... I just don't know it off the top of my head. Or again, you can just do the math yourself, because that's essentially all it is: look at the offset of the relevant MainUI element and use math to figure out the correct `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right` styles to set on `UIBits` (using refs, inside a `useEffect` handler).

Comment: P.S. If you have a library that generates both `UIBits` and `MainUI` for you, that makes this tricky, but still solvable.  In that case, your `useEffect` code will need to also move the elements around in the DOM (in addition to changing their styles to make them appear where you want visually).  Fundamentally there's no way to have those elements inside and not be hidden by the `overflow`: you *have* to move them out ... and using DOM manipulation/`useEffect` is the only way I can think of to do that.  In React it feels off ... but browser rules "win" in this case, so we have to work around.